# Mule Request Reply hangs when an exception

Tags: mule

I've a mule flow where I configured Request Reply scope. The flow is like below:

```
<flow name="RequestReplyFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <set-payload value="#['Sample Payload']" doc:name="Set Payload" />
    <request-reply doc:name="Request-Reply">
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="request" doc:name="VM" />
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="reply" doc:name="VM" />
    </request-reply>
</flow>
```

and

```
<flow name="RequestReplyFlow1">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="request" doc:name="VM" />
    <logger message="Executing with payload: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    <component class="org.ram.BusinessComponent" doc:name="Java" />
    <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

When the component `org.ram.BusinessComponent` throws an exception, the browser that calls the above flow just got hanged, not responding at all.

When the `org.ram.BusinessComponent` doesn't throw an exception the browser gets a response.

Can anyone please solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could reproduce the issue in Mule 3.6.2. The problem is because the flow is not redirecting to the request-reply to continue with the flow when an exception is thrown, in these cases you can specify the redirection manually in the "catch-exception" by adding the "vm:outbound-endpoint" with the "reply" path. Here is the example:

```
<flow name="RequestReplyFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <set-payload value="#['Sample Payload']" doc:name="Set Payload" />
    <request-reply doc:name="Request-Reply">
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="request" doc:name="VM" />
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="reply" doc:name="VM" />
    </request-reply>
</flow>

<flow name="RequestReplyFlow1">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="request" doc:name="VM" />
    <logger message="Executing with payload: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    <component class="org.ram.BusinessComponent" doc:name="Java" />
    <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="reply" doc:name="VM" />
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Comment: I edited the question to include `rollback-exception-strategy`. Can you please have look at it?

Comment: I think that it should be a new question. Please create a new question.

Comment: Okay. I've created a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770617/mule-request-reply-and-rollback-exception-strategy). Your answer is appreciated