# Mule Request Reply and Rollback Exception Strategy

Tags: mule

I've a mule flow where I configured Request Reply scope. The flow is like below:

```
<flow name="RequestReplyFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <set-payload value="#['Sample Payload']" doc:name="Set Payload" />
    <request-reply doc:name="Request-Reply">
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="request" doc:name="VM" />
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="reply" doc:name="VM" />
    </request-reply>
</flow>
```

and

```
<flow name="RequestReplyFlow1">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="request" doc:name="VM" />
    <logger message="Executing with payload: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    <component class="org.ram.BusinessComponent" doc:name="Java" />
    <rollback-exception-strategy maxRedeliveryAttempts="5" doc:name="Rollback Exception Strategy">
        <logger message="Will attempt redelivery" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    </rollback-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

I configure `rollback-exception-strategy` on the `request` VM inbound endpoint.

When the component org.ram.BusinessComponent throws an exception, what I expected is the message is redelivered to the inbound VM endpoint but it did not happen. Why?

Can anyone please solve the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using rollback exception strategy instead of default exception strategy for [unhandled exceptions](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/rollback-exception-strategy#use-rollback-exception-strategy-for-unhandled-exceptions), then you just have to specify the redirection manually in the "rollback-exception-strategy" by adding the "vm:outbound-endpoint" with the "reply" path, note that the maxRedeliveryAttempts was changed to "0" because your vm is not transactional:

```
<flow name="RequestReplyFlow1">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="request" doc:name="VM" />
    <logger message="Executing with payload: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    <component class="org.ram.BusinessComponent" doc:name="Java" />
    <rollback-exception-strategy maxRedeliveryAttempts="0" doc:name="Rollback Exception Strategy">
        <logger message="Will attempt redelivery" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="reply" doc:name="VM" />
    </rollback-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

When the vm is [transactional](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/rollback-exception-strategy#use-rollback-exception-strategy-for-transactions) then the value maxRedeliveryAttempts=5 makes sense because in that case Mule attempts message redelivery five (5) times. Then you can specify the redirection manually in the "rollback-exception-strategy" by adding the "vm:outbound-endpoint" with the "reply" path inside the "on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded" child element:

```
<flow name="RequestReplyFlow1">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="request" doc:name="VM" />
    <logger message="Executing with payload: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    <component class="org.ram.BusinessComponent" doc:name="Java" />
    <rollback-exception-strategy maxRedeliveryAttempts="0" doc:name="Rollback Exception Strategy">
        <logger message="Will attempt redelivery" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        <on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded>
            <logger message="redelivery attempt exceeded" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
            <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="reply" doc:name="VM" />
        </on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded>
    </rollback-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```